# SIM900A Strange Problem

Tags: pic, gsm, sim900

[image: SIM900A Module Circuit]

Please refer to above circuit.

I have a SIM900A module connected with the UART of a PIC. D1 toggles every second, using timer interrupt, to indicate that while loop is running satisfactorily. D2 toggles only when switch changes its state. "PORTB Interrupt on Change" is used to detect change in state of switch.

The circuit works correctly but as soon as a minute elapses and SMS is sent D2 toggles a number of times and multiple SMSs are sent instead of one indicating change in state of switch. This behavior is observed only when the switch is in closed state before sending SMS.

The problem cannot be of de-bouncing since if switch is closed initially before powering up the circuit and it remains in the same state before first minute even then the same problem is encountered.

The circuit works fine with a veroboard but started creating problems when I went to a PCB design.

What could be the possible reason and solution for this problem?

---

The above circuit is just part of the whole circuit.

U2 and U7 are voltage regulator but only one is used at a time. U2 is for 7805 and U7 is for LT1084. Only one of them is soldered.

RV1 and RV2 are potentiometers connected with output of two comparators of LM324(U6). RV3 is connected with LT1084 to adjust output voltage in case of using LT1084.

RSMD on the right side of board is 12mohm resistor.

U5 is MAX232.RL1 is a 5V relay and Q1 is a transistor. D2 is voltage reference for ADC while SW1 is a DIP switch to enable or disable the use of voltage reference.

[image]

Comment: Please note that  this works fine on veroboard but when I made its PCB, the problem appeared

Comment: Then, you will need to supply us the PCB design to let us seek for a problem with your layout..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/duFX0.png

Comment: U2 and U7 are voltage regulator but only one is used at a time. U2 is for 7805 and U7 is for LT1084. Only one of them is soldered.

RV1 and RV2 are potentiometers connected with output of two comparators of LM324(U6). RV3 is connected with LT1084 to adjust output voltage in case of using LT1084.

RSMD on the right side of board is 12mohm resistor.

U5 is MAX232.RL1 is a 5V relay and Q1 is a transistor. D2 is voltage reference for ADC while SW1 is a DIP switch to enable or disable the use of voltage reference.

Comment: Part numbers in the PCB layout are obscured. Please show the complete circuit diagram with component values. I don't see a power supply bypass capacitor across the 16F877, and why do you have resistor(?) in series with Vss?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott:Resistors whose label is inside its rectangular top silk are all jumpers. Hence resistor in series with Vss is actually a jumper. C1 and C2 are bypass capacitors near 7805. I have not used separate by pass capacitors at 16f877a.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott: All caps are 10uF except for C5 and C6 which are 22pF and C7,C8 which are 0.1uF. X2 is 4MHz while X1 is 20MHz. J1 is resistor array of 8 resistors 330ohm each. R3 is 10k, R4 4.7k, R8 and R15 10k, R10 1.5M, R11 1k, U3 is LED array of 10 LEDs, R36 and R37 330ohm each. R12 and R5 10k, R7 2.7k, R6 2.2k

Comment: @Bruce Abbott: link to topsilk is http://i.imgur.com/HZautuU.png. I am trying to make schematic as clear as possible since it is drawn poorly.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott: R13,R1,R17,R16 are all 10k. R38 330ohm, R9 22k, RV1,RV2,RV3,RV4 are 5k pot. RV3 and RV4 are not used in the circuit since they are connected with LT1084 and LM336 respectively which are not soldered yet. Resistor without label overlapping with RV4 is a jumper. RB1 is reset button, J4 and J3 are 2 pin and 3pin crimp shell respectively.

Comment: R2 is 1ohm resistor.

Comment: Before anything else, put a 100nF bypass capacitor directly across the PIC power pins. An MCU can go crazy if it gets glitches on the power supply.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott: I tried 100nF bypass cap but it still works the same.

Comment: Hopefully your PIC is getting good power now, so it's time to review your code. Think about what could cause spurious switch change detection - floating inputs on Port B?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott:Yes floating inputs can be a problem but the output of comparator is connected to port B. Also the circuit works without a problem on veroboard. If it was a problem in code, why should it work on veroboard every time?

Comment: Different layout = different signal coupling between traces, so a floating input may be OK on one board but not the other. Or perhaps the Veroboard circuit is not the same as the PCB and has some significant difference. You haven't  shown us the full schematic or any code and your pcb layout is largely indecipherable. How can you expect us to help when you won't give us the information we need?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly when the SMS is sent the module draws large currents and the regulator is not able to support it and there is a voltage drop on MCU power linie or IO pin. (If module and MCU are running on same power supply)

SIM900A draws around 2A when network operation takes place.

Or possibly UART lines of MCU are shorted to IO input interrupt line. And when data is sent on TX line of MCU or RX line of MCU then that causes multiple interrupts to MCU and SMS are sent.

Just a guess.

Comment: Mka needs to probe these signals with a digital storage oscilloscope and see what transients are happening.